# How to merge many directory in one directory by keeping th order?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to to copy numpy files in directory A to diretory B, by keeping their order on time.

```
import os
import shutil
DestFolder = 'D:\\Traces_Copie\\Simulations\\Traces4\\Trace4'
SrcFolder  = 'D:\\Traces_Copie\\Simulations\\Traces4\\Trace4_1'
os.chdir(SrcFolder)
list_files_Without_Sort=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
list_files_Sorted=sorted((list_files_Without_Sort),key=os.path.getmtime)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(list_files_Sorted, topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)
        shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, DestFolder)
```

It gives me this error:

```
    names = listdir(top)

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: Where in your code do you get this error? Where is line `names = listdir(top)` in your code?

Comment: I put the error as it is displayed for me . As I understand it is about this line: for root, dirs, files in os.walk(list_files_Sorted, topdown=True):

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk` takes a string but you're passing a list object. You can *walk* the directory without sorting (I don't see why you need to order independent copy ops):

```
import os
import shutil

destfolder = 'D:\\Traces_Copie\\Simulations\\Traces4\\Trace4'
srcfolder  = 'D:\\Traces_Copie\\Simulations\\Traces4\\Trace4_1'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcfolder, topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        src = os.path.join(root, name)
        shutil.copy2(src, destfolder)
```

Comment: I need  to keep the  order, I have some analyses to do that oblige me to use the order